# fullcalendar как отобразить день недели в ячейке вместе с датой

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

я использую fullcalendar, но столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно отобразить день недели в ячейке с датой, а также возле даты ставить текущий месяц как это можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
js:
$('.js-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                right: 'today',
                center: 'prev, title, next',
                left: ''
            },
            navLinks: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: exhibitionList,
            eventColor: '#3279b7',
            columnFormat: 'dddd',
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.logo){
                    element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<img class='fcalen__img' src="+event.logo+">").append("<span class='fcalen__city'>"+event.city+"</span>");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему через dayRender

```
$('.js-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                right: 'today',
                center: 'prev, title, next',
                left: ''
            },
            navLinks: true,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: exhibitionList,
            eventColor: '#3279b7',
            columnFormat: 'dddd',
            dayRender: function( date, cell ) {
                var weekDay = date.format("dddd");
                var month = date.format("MMMM");
                var day = date.format("D");
                cell.html("<span class='fcalen__week-day'>" + weekDay + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<div class='fcalen__month-name'>" + day + "  "  + month + "</div>");
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<img class='fcalen__img' src="+event.logo+">").append("<span> / <span><span class='fcalen__city'>" + event.country + " " + event.city + "</span>");
            }
        });
```